# How to use reset password on cartalyst sentry

Tags: laravel-4, cartalyst-sentry

[code example come from this](https://cartalyst.com/manual/sentry/users/reset-password)

I confused on example code I didn't login and
click link from email 
and get user id from?

```
 $user = Sentry::findUserById(1);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the example it not clear I found another function

`$user = Sentry::findUserByResetPasswordCode($code);`

Answer (score 0):

You can find user by the code, then you can login into application to change the password

```
try
{
  $user = Sentry::findUserByResetPasswordCode($code);

  if ($user->checkResetPasswordCode($code)){
    Sentry::login($user, false);
    return Redirect::route('application.reset_password');
  }
}
catch(\Cartalyst\Sentry\Users\UserNotFoundException $e)
{
  return Redirect::route('login')->with('message' , 'Code not valid');
}
```